# Como saber se dois períodos se interceptam?

Tags: java, data

Vamos supor que tenho 2 objetos que tem a seguinte propriedade:

```
Objeto 1: 
Date dataAtivacao;
Date dataDesativacao;

Objeto 2: 
Date dataAtivacao;
Date dataDesativacao;
```

Como saber se essas datas se "cruzam". Por exemplo:

```
EXEMPLO 1, ENTRADA:

Objeto1.getDataAtivacao = 10/10/2015
Objeto1.getDataDesativacao = 10/11/2015

Objeto2.getDataAtivacao = 15/10/2015
Objeto2.getDataDesativacao = 15/11/2015

Saída: Se interceptam.

EXEMPLO 2, ENTRADA:

Objeto1.getDataAtivacao = 10/10/2015
Objeto1.getDataDesativacao = 10/11/2015

Objeto2.getDataAtivacao = 11/11/2015
Objeto2.getDataDesativacao = 15/11/2015

Saída: Não se interceptam.
```

Como fazer isso? Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumindo que os períodos estão correctamente definidos, isto é, a data de inicio é sempre anterior à data de fim, então esta condição é suficiente para determinar se duas datas se interceptam:

```
(InicioPeriodo1 <= FimPeriodo2)  &&  (FimPeriodo1 >= InicioPeriodo2)
```

No teu caso em particular ficaria:

```
Objeto1.getDataAtivacao = 10/10/2015
Objeto1.getDataDesativacao = 10/11/2015

Objeto2.getDataAtivacao = 15/10/2015
Objeto2.getDataDesativacao = 15/11/2015


if (Objecto1.getDataActivacao <= Objecto2.getDataDesactivacao && Objecto1.getDataDesactivacao >= Objecto1.getDataActivacao)
   System.Out.Println("Interceptam");
else
   System.Out.Println("Não se interceptam");
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo! Valeuuu!